# How to create domain controlled jboss cluster between two jboss nodes and HTTPS enabled on both nodes

Tags: ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to create a jboss cluster with two jboss nodes (master and slave, both on different VMs). The configuration done for the two are as below:

Master:
In host.xml, ssl is added in the managementRealm tag:

```
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="<jboss-cert-folder>/jboss.jks" keystore-password="${VAULT::sslKeyStore::password::1}"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```

Also the interface is defined as below:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:<ip_of_master>}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:<ip_of_master>}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="<ip_of_master>"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Also on master, created two users: admin and slave. Both are Management users and in the ManagementRealm.

Slave:
On slave side, made the following changes to the host.xml

```
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="<jboss-cert-folder>/jboss.jks" keystore-password="${VAULT::sslKeyStore::password::1}"/>
                </ssl>
   <secret value="base 64 secret value generated at the time of slave user creation" />
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>

 <domain-controller>
    <!--local/-->
   <remote host="<ip of master>" port="9999"/>
 </domain-controller>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:<ip of slave>}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:<ip of slave>}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="<ip of slave>"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Now first restarted master jboss. Restart happened without any error. Then restarted slave jboss. Following error was seen:

```
[Host Controller] 15:14:11,985 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "hostname:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
[Host Controller] 15:14:11,990 ERROR [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010901: Could not connect to master. Aborting. Error was: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS010942: Unable to connect due to authentication failure.
[Host Controller] 15:14:12,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.2.2.GA (AS 7.3.2.Final-redhat-2) stopped in 17ms
15:14:12,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (reaper for Host Controller) JBAS012010: Process 'Host Controller' finished with an exit status of 99
15:14:12,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) JBAS012016: Shutting down process controller
15:14:12,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) JBAS012015: All processes finished; exiting
```

This is all the error displayed in console.log of slave jboss. Key exchange has been done properly because i am able to list the keys from master in the trustStore file of slave and vice-versa.

Please look into it and provide any suggestions.